# SELECT multiple rows WHERE matching two conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This would be better to show on my example:

I have table, where are stored users answers from one big form. Each form has 139 questions. These questions are stored in different table, joined when needed with questionID. For each user, there is an ID. I now need to make filters, to show only users matching one or **more** answers on specific questions.

For example, i want users, where question 14 has answer "yes", question 54 is not empty and question 100 is bigger than 10. This is how the table looks:

```
**userID** | **questionID** | **answer**

1            14               "yes"
1            54               "something"
1            100              "9"
2            14               "no"
2            54               "north
2            100              "50"
3            14               "yes"
3            54               "test"
3            100              "12"
```

as result i want only the **userID** 3 returned, because it meets all conditions.

This would be easy to reach with ColdFusion, as it allows query in queried results, but in PHP i haven't found any way. It is important to have chance to add random number of questions, not only three as in this example.

Comment: What is your table schema? (the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table`)

Comment: CREATE TABLE `leal_dotaznik` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `UID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `questionID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `answer` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3059 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try,

```
SELECT userID
FROM tableName
WHERE   (questionID = 14 AND
        answer = 'yes' ) OR
        (questionID = 54 AND
        answer <> 'empty') OR
        (questionid = 100 AND
        answer > 10)
GROUP BY userID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d385d/2)

Comment: How did you guess the OP's table structure?

Comment: @Jocelyn see the question above, there is a table :)

Comment: I see a text stating "These questions are stored in **different table**, joined when needed with questionID".

Comment: @Jocelyn oh yeah! haha my bad. I think I need to sleep :D

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. I think that this solution is more clean than the one from Matei Mihai and also a little bit faster according to query time. But thank you both for quick answers :)

Comment: yeah no joins but solved tricky. I liked HAVING COUNT(*) = 3. So +1

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT q.userID
  FROM questions q
  JOIN questions qq ON qq.userID=q.userID
       AND qq.questionID='54' AND qq.answer IS NOT NULL
  JOIN questions qqq ON qqq.userID=q.userID
       AND qqq.questionID='100' AND qqq.answer > 10
 WHERE q.questionID=14
   AND q.answer = 'yes'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
SELECT questionID, answer
FROM table
WHERE ( questionID = 14 AND answer = 'yes' ) 
OR ( questionID = 54 AND answer != '' )
OR ( questionID = 100 AND answer > 10 );
```

Comment: you have hardcoded the result user by userID = 3. By the way it was an example

Comment: Thank you, but anyway I think @Matei Mihai has the correct answer. He wants all conditions at once, not one of then at least.

Comment: This will not fulfill *all* conditions, only one of them.